# a simple measure theory question (from homework)

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Let X be a positive random variable independent of a standard Brownian motion B. Let
$M_t = B_{tX}$ for t > 0. We assume that the random variable X is $F_t$ measurable for all t $\geq$ 0, require to show: $M_t$ is adapted to the filtration $(F_t)$.

The question doesn't tell me what $(F_t)$.  I guess it is the filtration generated by B ?

Comment: When filtration isn't specified, it is generaly assumed to be the one generated by the stochastic process itself

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\mathcal F_t=\sigma(B_s;0\leqslant s\leqslant t)$, this is obviously false: take $X=2$ with full probability, then $M_t=B_{2t}$ is not measurable with respect to $\mathcal F_t$ (except when $t=0$).

Comment: I understand.  Thank you for your answer!