# a question about covariation in stochastic integration

Tags: stochastic-integrals

Let H, K be bounded previsibe process.  M, N be two local martingales.  How can I prove $d<H.M, K.N>_t = H_tK_td<M,N>_t$

$<M>$ means the quadratic variation of M.

Thanks

Comment: What happened to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/215103)?

Comment: ?? $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $

Comment: Any ideas? Or suggest me some book for this question.  Thanks!

Comment: Any idea about what happened to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/215103)?

Comment: Thanks for your attention.  It seems to be a basic thm. But I just don't know how to solve it.  Tomorrow I will have a exercise class.  Hope I will get the answer.